# NDSolveValue BVP that encounters infinity

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, warning-messages, boundary-conditions

**Problem setup**:

I'm trying to solve the following, quite hairy, first order BVP problem, with four unknown functions $\phi, \theta, p_\phi, p_\theta$, and boundary conditions at $\phi(0), \phi(1), \theta(0), \theta(1)$:

```
sys = {Derivative[1][ϕ][t] == (
    Sin[ϕ[
       t]] (pθ[
         t] (1/Sqrt[2] - (Cot[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[
          2]) + (pϕ[t] Csc[θ[t]]^2 Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[
       2] - Cot[θ[t]]/Sqrt[2] - Cos[ϕ[t]]/Sqrt[2]))/Sqrt[
    2] + 2 π, 
  Derivative[1][θ][
    t] == ((Cos[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - 
      Sin[θ[t]]/Sqrt[2]) ((
      Cos[ϕ[t]] (pθ[t] Cos[θ[t]] + 
         Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
      Cos[θ[t]] - pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
      pϕ[t] Csc[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2]), 
  Derivative[1][pθ][
    t] == ((Cos[ϕ[t]] (pθ[t] Cos[θ[t]] + 
         Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
      Cos[θ[t]] - pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
      pϕ[t] Csc[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2]) ((
      Cos[ϕ[t]] (pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]] - 
         Cos[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
      pθ[t] Cos[θ[t]] + Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
      pϕ[t] Cot[θ[t]] Csc[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]])/
      Sqrt[2]), 
  Derivative[1][pϕ][t] == (1/Sqrt[
   2])((Cos[ϕ[t]] (pθ[t] Cos[θ[t]] + 
         Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
      Cos[θ[t]] - pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
      pϕ[t] Csc[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[
      2]) (Sin[ϕ[t]] (pθ[t] Cos[θ[t]] + 
         Sin[θ[t]]) + 
      pϕ[t] Csc[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]]), ϕ[0] == 
   1.4903654113633533, ϕ[1] == 7.773550718542939, θ[0] == 
   0.08017201109143635, θ[1] == 0.08017201109143635}
```

**Attempt 1**: Using NDSolveValue

```
NDSolveValue[sys, {ϕ[t], θ[t], pϕ[t], 
pθ[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This only produces error messages about encountering infinity during the calculation:
[image: Infinity and NDSolve error message]

**Attempt 2**: Trying to get a better sense of the system by solving the same system with variable initial conditions (replacing the two target final values $\phi(1), \theta(1)$, with initial conditions $p_\phi(0), p_\theta(0)$)

```
sysinitial = {Derivative[1][ϕ][t] == 
2 π + (
Sin[ϕ[t]] (-(Cos[ϕ[t]]/Sqrt[2]) - Cot[θ[t]]/Sqrt[
   2] + (1/Sqrt[2] - (Cos[ϕ[t]] Cot[θ[t]])/Sqrt[
      2]) pθ[t] + (
   Csc[θ[t]]^2 pϕ[t] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2]))/Sqrt[
2], Derivative[1][θ][
t] == ((Cos[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - 
  Sin[θ[t]]/Sqrt[2]) ((
  Cos[ϕ[t]] (Cos[θ[t]] pθ[t] + 
     Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
  Cos[θ[t]] - pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
  Csc[θ[t]] pϕ[t] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2]), 
Derivative[1][pθ][
t] == ((Cos[ϕ[t]] (Cos[θ[t]] pθ[t] + 
     Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
  Cos[θ[t]] - pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
  Csc[θ[t]] pϕ[t] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[2]) ((
  Cos[θ[t]] pθ[t] + Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] + (
  Cos[ϕ[t]] (-Cos[θ[t]] + 
     pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] - (
  Cot[θ[t]] Csc[θ[t]] pϕ[t] Sin[ϕ[t]])/
  Sqrt[2]), 
Derivative[1][pϕ][
t] == (((
  Cos[ϕ[t]] (Cos[θ[t]] pθ[t] + 
     Sin[θ[t]]))/Sqrt[2] + (
  Cos[θ[t]] - pθ[t] Sin[θ[t]])/Sqrt[2] - (
  Csc[θ[t]] pϕ[t] Sin[ϕ[t]])/Sqrt[
  2]) (Cos[ϕ[t]] Csc[θ[t]] pϕ[
    t] + (Cos[θ[t]] pθ[t] + 
     Sin[θ[t]]) Sin[ϕ[t]]))/Sqrt[2], ϕ[0] == ϕi, 
pϕ[0] == pϕi, θ[0] == θi, 
pθ[0] == pθi}
```

Parametric solutions:

```
solic = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  sysinitial, {ϕ[t], θ[t], pϕ[t], pθ[t]}, {t, 
   0, 1}, {ϕi, θi, pϕi, pθi}]
```

looking specifically at the two functions, $\theta, \phi $, that I want to satisfy my boundary conditions and fixing the two initial conditions I know I want while allowing the other two initial conditions to vary.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{solic[1.4903654113633533, 0.08017201109143635, p1, p2][[1]], 
   solic[1.4903654113633533, 0.08017201109143635, p1, p2][[2]]}, {t, 
   0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2*Pi + 1.5}}], 
   {{p1, 0.088}, -2, 2}, {{p2, 2}, -4, 4}]
```

Playing with this I see that there are sudden jumps in the solutions and ranges of initial conditions that seem to make the solutions blow up.
[image]
[image]

I try to use some of the more reasonable looking initial conditions to help NDSolve

```
NDSolveValue[sys, {ϕ[t], θ[t], pϕ[t], 
  pθ[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"Shooting", 
   "StartingInitialConditions" -> {ϕ[0] == 
      1.4903654113633533`, θ[0] == 0.08017201109143635`, 
     pϕ[0] == 0, pθ[0] == 2}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}]
```

But I again encounter issues
[image]

**plea for help**:

I very much expect that a solution to my BVP problem should exist but I am not sure what to try next and would appreciate any help on how to get my numerics working!

Comment: The problem seems to be arising when $\theta \to n \pi$, at which point the coordinates you're using are singular.  I wonder whether you might actually be better off recasting the problem as a constrained 3D (6-D?) problem using coordinates $x$, $y$ and $z$ subject to the constraint $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = const.$;  Mathematica might be able to solve this as a differential-algebraic system instead.

Comment: Alternately, you might be able to use `WhenEvent` somehow to "skip" over the singularity (something like "when $\theta \to n \pi$, switch the sign of $p_\theta$ and switch $\phi \to \phi + \pi$".  This would correspond to the trajectory going "over the pole".

Comment: Hi @MichaelSeifert, I will definitely try solving in alternative coordinates - but one issue I have with this is that in the spherical coordinates I am using currently I am able to specify the same point on the sphere using more than one choice of B.C. I have previously found solutions for b.c. like $(\phi(0), \theta(0)) = (\phi(1),\theta(1))$ and here I would like to find solutions with b.c. like $(\phi(0), \theta(0)) = (\phi(0) + 2 \pi, \theta(0))$ - these trajectories should exist (winding and not winding). But I'm not sure how to ask for them in cartesian coordinates!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks! I will look into WhenEvent, I have not used this in Mathematica before